# Call a SQL procedure, for each group by

Tags: sql

I am trying to call a procedure for each group of data. For example, I have a list of customers and movie's features that they like. Is a relation one to many, I have many records for one specific customer in dataset. Therefore, what I am trying to do is for each specific customer to apply a clustering algorithm. Need some help with what statement should I apply this on SQL.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get your question, but not enough reputation to comment. Thus, I'll make some assumptions and answer to the best of my understanding with them.

For example with SQLite (this is one of the simplest, variations possible in different dialects), let's assume your data is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE "Customer" (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  UNIQUE (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "Movie" (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  customer INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  movie VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  UNIQUE (id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(customer) REFERENCES "Customer" (id)
);
```

Let's populate with some data:

```
INSERT INTO Movie (id, customer, movie) VALUES(0, 0, 'Rambo');
INSERT INTO Movie (id, customer, movie) VALUES(1, 0, 'Rocky');
INSERT INTO Movie (id, customer, movie) VALUES(2, 1, 'Mamma Mia');
INSERT INTO Movie (id, customer, movie) VALUES(3, 1, 'Grease');
INSERT INTO Movie (id, customer, movie) VALUES(4, 0, 'Terminator');
```

As long as you are happy with applying some aggregate functions, you can just use a single SELECT like this:

```
SELECT
  customer, MAX(id),
  COUNT(DISTINCT id), AVG(LENGTH(movie)), SUM(LENGTH(movie))
FROM Movie GROUP BY customer;
```

If you need to get data from the Customer table, you might need to make a join like this:

```
SELECT
  Customer.name, Customer.id, MAX(Movie.id),
  COUNT(DISTINCT Movie.id), AVG(LENGTH(Movie.movie)), SUM(LENGTH(Movie.movie))
FROM Movie
JOIN Customer on Movie.customer=Customer.id
GROUP BY customer;
```

If you want to do k-means, SQLite is quite limited, but with other dialects you can still do it. See [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.700.6959&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for an example. On the internet one can easily find examples in [PostgreSQL](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/multi-dimensional-clustering-using-k-means-postgres), [MySQL](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/k-means-clustering-in-mysql/), [SQL Server](https://gist.github.com/jcbozonier/4006373),... you could google yours.

Most other SQL dialects would have a richer set of predefined functions. For more complicated analysis you might need to define your own functions, and probably work with the results out of your SQL.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! My idea is that I will create a procedure separetely where I run a Kmeans algorithm. And for each group by customer to call this procedure. I am not able to find a way how to apply this in sql. Sorry if my question looks a bit shallow but I am quite new in sql.

Comment: I have updated my answer about k-means. Please update the question with details regarding the SQL dialect you use (or intend to use), the fact that it's k-means that you are interested in, and possibly the language you use if you want to do it externally.